# Add tilt direction as a line

Tags: python, animation, 3d, rotation, scatter-plot

Í currently have a scatterplot that looks like this:
[image]. Each point reprents the direction of rotation (tilt/spin) of a ball.

To make it more comprehensive I would like to replace the points with lines showing directions of the rotation. I would love if the representation could render a 3D effect, with the lines animated to rotate around the ball. The goal would be to have something like this:
[image].

For reference, my data is in a table with a column for the horizontal position of the point and a column for the vertical position. It looks like this:
[image]

I have tried different methods using Python, R, and Power BI visuals. The final goal would be to have this visual in a Power BI dashboard but any help in on to do something similar in R and/or Python is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: the matplotlib offers animation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html  but what have you tried and where are you stuck ?

Comment: @D.L I am completely stuck when trying to substitute the data point with an arch/line pointing in that direction